# How to set Jenkins Parameter from cmd

Tags: jenkins, cmd

I have this `Execute Windows Batch Command`in Jenkins that I want to read it's returned value

```
type foo.txt | find /C "%param%" > temp.txt
set /p result=<temp.txt
del temp.txt
```

And I want to return `result` value to Jenkins parameter. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I have a string Parameter in Jenkins called RESULT_PARAM

after running the code above or any other code, it does not matter, I want to read the result to put it into RESULT_PARAM

Comment: What is your ```Jenkins parameter```? Please explain in more details. You can see that ```set /P RESULT= < temp.txt``` will give you ```echo %RESULT%```.

Comment: please see my edit, acutally it does not matter what the code does, I simply want to save it's output to Jenkins global param

Answer (score 1):

When you spawn a process, it inherits a copy of environmental variables from the parent. When you chance an environment variable, it only affects that spawned process, it does not propagate back up to the parent (or other children). Even if you explicitly set the variable as global, it will not take effect until the process is restarted.

For the benefit of "clean environment", Jenkins spawns a child process from itself, for every build. This way, when the build is finished, the child process is discarded, and your OS environment is not polluted.

```
- ENVIRONMENT (global variables)
|
------ Jenkins process (copy of ENVIRONMENT variables)
|       |
|       ----- Build 1 (copy of Jenkins process variables)
|       |      |
|       |      ------ %RESULT% variable changed
|       |
|       ----- Build 2 (copy of Jenkins process variables)
|
------ Other process (copy of ENVIRONMENT variables)
```

If your `Build 1` changes any environment variable, it does not affect `Build 2` or other OS processes that are running.

Even if you use `SETX` command to force the variable to be propagated back to global ENVIRONMENT, your Jenkins process will not pick it up, unless restarted, and neither will Jenkins child build processes, since they get a copy of Jenkins process.

### Workaround

Use **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)**.

At the end of your job, write the variable you want into a properties file.
`echo result=%result% > myvars.props`
This file should list, line by line, key-value pairs of variables and their values.

In the next build, you can use EnvInject plugin to read the properties file, and inject these variables into the spawned process. From that point, you can use `%result%` as any other global environment variable.